# Should I tell the editor I'm declining a review invitation because the authors are hostile about feedback?

Tags: peer-review, etiquette

I have been invited to review a paper for a good journal. The paper is certainly on my expertise areas. However, I have reviewed papers for the same authors in the past (and accepted some/most of them), and they tend to be quite hostile and rude in their replies. I try to be polite with my comments, even with the major ones, but these authors seem to take simple things such as pointing out typos as a big offense and reply with a very harsh tone. Editors seem to not care at all about this, perhaps because one of the authors is an authority in this area.

I will decline the invitation. **My question is**: Should I indicate this reason for declining in my reply to the invitation?

This is, in this case, I am a good fit for reviewing the paper but my reason for declining is that I do not want to go through this sort of unpleasant moments again.

Comment: Will the authors be given the names of the reviewers?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche No, it is an anonymous review.

Comment: What exactly is the question: Whether you should decline to review, or whether you should indicate your reason to do so while you already made up your mind to decline?

Comment: @Snijderfrey Whether or not I should indicate the reason. I will definitely decline the invitation.

Comment: Why not state the reasons?

Comment: What is the worry? that the editor will blacklist you?  there is no need to provide any reasons.  In many cases, I'm sure that some invited reviewers don't even bother to reply to an invite, let alone provide a reason for the rejection.   I reject invites from journals I don't publish it.  Yet, I continue to get invite from them.

Comment: How come you know the authors of the papers you will review? Aren't these reviews double-blind?

Comment: @Stef This is not a double-blind peer-review journal. This is a single-blind one. Not all journals are double-blind.

Comment: Write exactly that to the editor.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As you feel apprehension over the refereeing process here, and the expected responses of the authors you **definitely should** decline the referee request. This is both for your own sake, but also because this is likely to bias your report in one way or another.

My suggestion for what to tell the editor would be that you have a conflict of interest, and are thus unable to referee papers by these authors. Do not elaborate further. This conveys the information that it is the author, not the topic or your general willingness. It is factually correct, without maligning (whether justified or not) anyone.

Comment: You don’t even need to decline because you believe you would be biased.  What you’ve described might later give the appearance of bias.  Avoiding the appearance of bias would be sufficient reason to decline this, although I agree with Arno that you should say the more neutral “conflict of interest.”

Comment: ...except OP doesn't have a conflict of interest.

Comment: @henning They do! The conflict is between their interest in not receiving an angry response to their review and their interest in providing a rigorous critique of the submitted paper. If they have a bit of a vindictive streak, they also might feel a bit of an interest in really showing it to that jerk next time.

Comment: although this is meant to be anonymous, there is every chance that OP's identity will somehow become known or guessed by the hostile authors, who may exert their revenge on OP when it comes time for OP to submit the paper. This is how that works, boys and girls

Comment: @Deipatrous, if the authors are *that* hostile, one should definitely refuse to review their papers.

Comment: Strictly speaking. "No." is a complete sentence.

Comment: @Arno That's not what "conflict of interest" means; it is unwise to Humpty-Dumpty a word when you're intending to be clear in your communications.

Comment: @Xerxes except that *is* what [conflict of interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_of_interest) means: "An 'interest' is a commitment, obligation, duty or goal associated with a particular social role or practice.". they have their primary interest: a duty of giving an unbiased review of a paper; and a secondary interest: not receiving an angry response, and therefore not potentially having a bad day

Comment: @Arno Should I declare a conflict of interest to my employer because I'm lazy? The conflict is between my interest in receiving a paycheck for performing the tasks I'm contracted for, and my interest in slacking off.

Comment: @somebody In American Business English (east coast flavor), "conflict of interest" doesn't fit here. The only way you could use "conflict of interest" here is if you were being funny/sarcastic or being disingenuous. (Fortunately for the OP, "Sorry, I can't review this one." is perfectly fine, no reason needed.)

Comment: oh hmm... is this a situation in which business english is normally used? (if not, i guess maybe it's normal to assume that such terms are used in the business sense anyway... in which case fair enough)

Comment: If I read "conflict of interest" I would immediately assume that the reviewer is working in the same field and the results of the paper conflict with the reviewer's work. It wouldn't occur to me that the reviewer might have a problem with the author's behavior. I really feel _conflict of interest_ will be misleading and should not be used.

Answer (score 53):

Reviewing is a purely voluntary activity that you are providing for free. In particular by reviewing a work, your are doing both the journal and the authors a favour (regardless whether you recommend to accept or reject). As a reviewer you should not have to put up with any abuse from the authors, or for that matter the authors wasting your time by not seriously considering your comments.

If you have had a bad experience reviewing the works of certain author(s), you are perfectly in your right to decline to review any of their future work (I certainly have a growing blacklist of authors reviewing whose work I consider a waste of my time and energy). Also, by all means, let the editor know why you are declining the review. This will help them understand why they are having trouble finding reviewers for certain authors, and maybe encourage them to take more proactive action on abusive behaviour by authors (or reviewers for that matter).

I strongly disagree you should phrase this as having a conflict of interest. This disguises the problem and suggests that the problem resides in your personal relation with the authors, when it is the authors' (unilateral) behaviour that is the issue.

Comment: *Conflict of interest = the problem resides in your personal relation with the authors* - Right, and I don't see how this would appear as an issue. That's exactly what CoI is for. The conflict can be of many type, and most of these would be perfectly reasonable to anyone. On the other hand, declaring the other party as *rude* would be unprofessional and likely backfire, regardless whether it's true.

Comment: @Neinstein I wouldn't necessarily use the word *rude*. But: "Sorry, I have no interest in reviewing the works of these authors, since past experiences have shown this to be an unproductive use of my time." is a perfectly fine response to somebody asking you to donate your time.

Comment: "Conflict of Interest" is where you are in a position where you might be tempted to act in your own interests rather than the job you are meant to be doing. For example when the paper duplicates work you already have in progress, and you might want to get it rejected so you can publish first. "I think the authors are rude" is not a conflict of interest - it's just a personal relation problem.

Comment: @DJClayworth Hypothetically, let's say your relative published a paper. Wouldn't it be a clear conflict of interest if you reviewed it? If possible favoritism counts as conflict of interest, why shouldn't it count in the other way? Supposedly, OP harbors bad enough feelings towards the authors that it's a concern.

Comment: @PasserBy If reviewers recused themselves on CoI grounds whenever they have an opinion on the authors, no papers would ever get reviewed (or at least not by peer specialists). Also it is unclear whether the OP has any strong feelings regarding the authors, other than not liking how they conduct themselves during peer review.

Comment: @mmeent It sounds like the crux is what OP thinks about the authors then. More to the point, it is not a question of whether it's just a personal relation problem, but the degree of animosity.

Comment: @DJClayworth If one might be tempted to give muted criticism rather than useful criticism, in order to not receive a rude reply, then that seems to be a conflict of interest by your definition.

Comment: @kaya3 Still not really a conflict of interest

Comment: @PasserBy Yes that would be  conflict of interest. But that's nothing like the case here.

Comment: @kaya3 I think that's just a bias, not a conflict of interest.

Comment: @chepner I merely point out that the definition offered (*"Conflict of Interest" is where you are in a position where you might be tempted to act in your own interests rather than the job you are meant to be doing*) is met in this case. Perhaps the reason it doesn't feel like a conflict of interest is because *everybody* has an interest in not receiving rude replies, whereas a conflict of interest needs to be something specific to oneself such that the same conflict wouldn't apply to somebody else who might do the job instead.

Answer (score 4):

Decline and explicitly give your honest reason. However, don't do so in writing, as written communication is prone to misunderstanding of tone or intent. Write a brief mail requesting a phone conversation with the editor.

This gives you the chance either to open the editor's eyes, or to learn why their view differs from yours.

Comment: I agree about avoiding stating the specific reason *via email* as [the internet is written in ink](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/173958/69206).

Answer (score 1):

There are benefits of *not* declining the review. Especially for the case when the manuscript is from your field, to have participation and a word to say is important. You should remember that you are the one who shapes the field (together with your hostile colleagues).

Pragmatically, imagine a situation that some of your important papers were not cited by the aforementioned people. By reviewing their manuscript you have a chance to point this out. Your expertise can also be beneficial for improving the manuscript.

By declining the review, you will miss these opportunities, and, potentially, the manuscript will be reviewed by less qualified people.

As for the "pointing out typos as a big offense". Simply do not point out typos, it is not the job of referee to do that. Many do that *bona fide*, but you are not obliged. Focus on the essential things and escalate it quickly to the editor (divisional editor) if responses are not proper (not follow common rules of scientific discus). As it is expected from the authors that a manuscript must be rigorous, so is the review. Sloppy reviews should not be tolerated. If you have nothing to say and point out typos just to write something, it is a bad style.

Answer (score -1):

Nooooooooo.

Make up some excuse that is not likely to backfire.

I believe you when you say they are unpleasant and feel entitled to do so because they consider themselves top dog in the field.

The editor is neutral at best. But the editor may also have a beer with dr top dog at a conference and spill the beans.

Comment: The best answer is probably still to neutrally declare a conflict of interest and leave it at that. But this response is much more realistic and frank about the potential danger of running afoul the Old Boys' Club. In principle, the OP should be able to be honest, but it could be personally very problematic for them, especially if they're ECR.